# Disposing BindingSource breaks DataGridView DataSource

Tags: .net, vb.net, dispose, bindingsource

Brief :  I have code which works if I don't dispose of the BindingSource after it has been assigned to DataGridView.DataSource but breaks if I do dispose it - why?  Do I need to worry about disposing this?

```
Public Sub GridViewUpdate()
        Dim cn As New System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection
        Dim SQL As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand
        Dim tbl As New DataTable
        Dim adp As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter
        Dim Bds As New BindingSource

        DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()

        cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = C:\path\data.sdf"
        SQL = cn.CreateCommand
        SQL.CommandText = "SELECT myfields FROM myTable  ORDER BY field1 DESC, field2 ASC"
        cn.Open()
        adp = New SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter(SQL)
        adp.Fill(tbl)
        Bds.DataSource = tbl

        DataGridView1.DataSource = Bds

        cn.Close()
        cn.Dispose()
        SQL.Dispose()
        adp.Dispose()
        tbl.Dispose()
        Bds.Dispose()   '*** <<--- This breaks it - GridView becomes empty

End Sub
```

So, what is going on here?  When I set DataGridView1.DataSource = Bds does it just do this as a reference?  How does Bds get disposed once the procedure exits?  Does garbage collection pick it up if I assign something else to DataGridView1.DataSource? Do I need to worry about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, got it!

DataGridView1.DataSource = Bds.DataSource

I guess using = Bds just creates a reference but = Bds.DataSource does not.

Disposing the BindingSource does not cause problems this way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the datasource is referenced to your Datatable. 
Just try

> Bds.DataSource = tbl.copy

Comment: This does not work - the problem is when disposing Bds, not tbl.  Figured it out, though - posted my own answer below.